# Internet Connected but cannot visit websites

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, proxy

My laptop is Elitebook 745 G2 running Ubuntu 14.04, new installed. It has dual OS: Ubuntu and Windows. The internet service works well in Windows, but cannot work in Ubuntu, though it is connected and get an IP address. The internet has a proxy server, so I set the proxy setting in the network manager, but still...And, firefox cannot work neither with the "auto-proxy" setting.

But it is weird that my another laptop can works well. Firefox works with auto-proxy.

If more information is needed, I will provide them.

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102244/firefox-use-system-proxy-settings-but-where-are-these) from [unix.se] might help

Comment: does `ping -c 4 google.com` give you any output? how about `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`

Comment: results are same, 100% packet loss

Comment: do you connect through wi-fi?

Answer (score 0):

Does your proxy setting is of type user-authnetication ? , Once setup your connections using Network Manager , go to /etc/Network-manager/system-connection and open the file which has same name as that of your connection, open the file and replace the password field with your user authentication password (i.e. password given in the proxy setting) save the file and reconnect , and the file should be edited with root permissions, I hope this works :)